# git-pull cannot be used without a working tree

Tags: git

I'm trying to pull from a remote repo I've just set up and I'm getting the message
git-pull cannot be used without a working tree

Everything I've read seems to point at my .git directory but it seems fine

```
git branch
```

gives the output

```
* master
```

and

```
git ls-tree --full-tree -r HEAD
```

list loads of entries like this

```
100644 blob c825c0607f77e1df4e05920037a2ce09c08e5180app/assets/javascripts/ready.js
```

which looks correct and makes me think I have managed to push the files correctly to this repo ?

```
git status
```

give the output

```
fatal: This operation must be run in a work tree
```

and
   ls -l .git
gives

```
drwxrwxr-x 2 roy roy 4096 Feb  6 14:24 branches
-rw-rw-r-- 1 roy roy   66 Feb  6 14:24 config
-rw-rw-r-- 1 roy roy   73 Feb  6 14:24 description
-rw-rw-r-- 1 roy roy   23 Feb  6 14:24 HEAD
drwxrwxr-x 2 roy roy 4096 Feb  6 14:24 hooks
drwxrwxr-x 2 roy roy 4096 Feb  6 14:24 info
drwxrwxr-x 4 roy roy 4096 Feb  6 14:24 objects
drwxrwxr-x 4 roy roy 4096 Feb  6 14:24 refs
```

which does seem a bit odd, as it looks just like it did before the push.

can anyone help me with what I'm doing wrong?
Is there something I have to do before I can do a git pull ? am I confused by that ls-tree command and the files haven't been pushed?

Comment: Is this a bare repo that you're trying to pull to?

Comment: @cHao. Yes I did git --bare init. Then on client I connected to it with git remote add origin roy@....... and pushed. git ls-remote on the client gives 168c3cb6118b84b495810cd9295eb41dc23b7fa1 HEAD
168c3cb6118b84b495810cd9295eb41dc23b7fa1 refs/heads/master

Comment: well, as Git is telling you, those operations do not make sense without a working tree (which a bare repo does not have). there is no status (as there is no working tree which could have a status), and you cannot do merges (which could have conflicts and thus require a working tree to resolve those)

Comment: @Nevik. So I have something very wrong then? I have a client with my code on it, I have a server on another machine. and I'm trying to set up a repo on the server and push to it , then get my code out of the repo and onto the server.

Comment: then you will need second clone on the server. http://gitolite.com/deploy.html might give you some pointers

Comment: @Nevik Ah right, I get it now i think, I need a server and 2 clients. Thanks for the pointers

Comment: If you want two working copies, then you'll also want a bare repo between them that both can push to and pull from, and you'll want to *only* modify stuff in the bare repo via push or fetch.  Otherwise, things get really weird.

Comment: @cHao. Yeah I get it now. Thanks to the tip from Nevik I've got it working.

Comment: Thanks @cHao - I have a bare repo which "failed to push some refs ... Merge the remote changes ...."; and was trying to update it using `git pull` which failed with this message -- and finally managed to update it with `git fetch`. Cheers!

Answer (score 18):

It seems you are working in a bare repository.

A bare repository is just like an ordinary one, except it has no working directory associated.
Being `pull` a `fetch` plus a `merge`, it cannot be applied to bare repositories.

In details:

A git repository, after all, is just a `.git` directory with a defined set of metadata stored in special directories (like `refs`, where local and remote branches are stored, and `objects`, which contains all the file contents, and so on).

Usually, a git repository is associated with a so called Working directory, which is the checkout of a certain commit: the developer can use the Working directory to perform modifications to the source code, and hence prepare the next commit.

Yet, sometimes, there's no need to have a Working directory. The most common case is when a repository is hosted in a shared server and it is used as the central, shared place used by developers to integrate their code. The repository must store all the information (hence, it has its own copy of the `.git` directory), and developers can push their contribution to it, but no developers are meant to directly work on it; so, no Working directory is provided. This is a bare repository.

Now, there are some git commands that operate on the Working directory. These commands are not working on a bare repository, since it lacks a Working directory.

`git pull` is one of them. `git pull` is the combination of `git fetch` and `git merge`. Now, `git fetch` involves only the `.git` directory, so it can be performed on a bare repository. On the other side, `git merge` requires a merge on the Working Directory to be performed. And since the working directory is not present, the command will fail.

`pull` and `merge` are not the only commands that cannot be performed on a bare repository. I strongly suggest you yo have a look to [this interactive map](http://ndpsoftware.com/git-cheatsheet.html#loc=remote_repo;) which will help you to select which operations cannot be performed on a bare repository ([see the amazing Interactive Git Cheatsheet](http://ndpsoftware.com/git-cheatsheet.html))

[image]